# How to write xpath for dynamically changing ID and ID is same for all the elements in the form

Tags: automated-testing

In my application one form is there having 10 elements.All elements are having same ID but with different number at the end.I want to locate all the elements.Can anyone give me xpath please.

```
@FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='ext-gen1095']")
WebElement period_type;
@FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='ext-gen1472']")
WebElement months;
@FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='ext-gen1097']")
WebElement period_start;
@FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='ext-gen1464']")
WebElement submit;
@FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='ext-gen1482']")
WebElement clear;
```

Comment: Share your html screenshot/code

Comment: did you try to construct any dynamic locator? Look at this link once http://www.testerlogic.com/handling-dynamic-elements-in-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Try to put some tokenValue along with xpath(for changing value) and write a method in java to replace this token when required.

Answer (score 3):

1.Use **starts-with** function.

In your case XPath's ID attribute, `ext-gen1` part remains same every time.

```
 //*[starts-with(@id,'ext-gen1')]
```

2.Look for other attributes which are not changing continuously for Ex. `class, name, type, tabindex` etc and use **and** function in between the XPath.

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'ext-gen1') and contains(@name,'----')]
```

Comment: How can I use same xpath to locate all the elements in the form ?All  attributes are same for all the elements only number is changing in ID

Comment: Can you add your html code, so that it will be clearly understood the situation.

Comment: @Jeevan why do you need the same xpath to locate all the elements on the form?